# Trying to write a C function to read in stdin to elements of a struct

Tags: c, struct

I have no idea how to call the function or what arguments to put in it. I've written the code in the main function, but I want to put it in a separate function I can call into main later. Would love some help on how I can do this!

The input comes from stdin

Here is the code (in the main function) that I want to put into a separate function:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* * * Define Constants * * */
#define WORD_LEN 22
#define MAX_NUM_POS_TAGS 5
#define SIZE_POS_TAG 4
#define MAX_NUM_VAR_FORMS 4
#define VAR_FORM_LEN 25
#define MAX_DICT_WORDS 100

/* * * Typedefs * * */

typedef char word_line_one[WORD_LEN+1];
typedef char word_line_two[MAX_NUM_POS_TAGS+1];
typedef char word_line_three[SIZE_POS_TAG+VAR_FORM_LEN*SIZE_POS_TAG+1];


//getword function prototype 
int getword(char W[], int limit);
//check_if_valid function prototype
int check_if_valid(char in_char);
//stage1 function
int stage1(char ln1[], char ln2[], char ln3[]);

//main function 

//stage 1 
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    //define the struct for one word 
    struct
    {
        word_line_one line_one;
        word_line_two line_two;
        word_line_three line_three;
    }one_word_dict_t;
    
    //reading line 1 
    char temp1[WORD_LEN+1];
    getword(temp1, WORD_LEN+1);
    strncpy(one_word_dict_t.line_one, temp1,WORD_LEN+1 );
    
    //reading line 2 
    getword(one_word_dict_t.line_two,MAX_NUM_POS_TAGS+1);//do something about spaces in between tags!
    
    
    //reading line 3
    
    getword(one_word_dict_t.line_three,SIZE_POS_TAG+VAR_FORM_LEN*SIZE_POS_TAG+1);
    
    //printing the word in the format:
    
    printf("==========================Stage 1==========================\n"); 
    printf("Word 0: %s\n", one_word_dict_t.line_one);
    printf("POS: %s\n", one_word_dict_t.line_two);
    printf("Form: %s\n", one_word_dict_t.line_three);
    //stage 1 ends here 
    
    

}

//getword function def 
/* Extract a single word out of the standard input, of not
   more than limit characters. Argument array W must be
   limit+1 characters or   bigger.    */
int
getword(char W[], int limit) 
{
    int c, len=0;
    /* first, skip over any non alphabetics */
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF && !check_if_valid(c)) 
    {
        /* do nothing more */
    }
    if (c==EOF) 
    {
        return EOF;
    }
    /* ok, first character of next word has been found */
    W[len++] = c;
    while (len<limit && (c=getchar())!=EOF && check_if_valid(c)) 
    {
        /* another character to be stored */
        W[len++] = c;
    }
    /* now close off the string */
    W[len] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

//check if valid function, used in modified version of getword():
int check_if_valid(char in_char)
{
    
    if ((('A'<=in_char)&&(in_char<='Z')) || (('a'<=in_char)&&(in_char<='z')) || 
        (('0'<=in_char)&&(in_char<='9')))
    
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
        
    
}
```

Comment: Just write a function that takes a pointer to the struct.

Comment: I think this is de-serialization. You are probably going have to tell us what the data is, at least, and how you are going to use it. Do you have control over the format, or it is handed to you?

Comment: Data is just handed to me from the stdin, and I have to read each line into a different element of the struct

Comment: `typedef char word_line_one[WORD_LEN+1];` Do not use typedef arrays. They are confusing. `one_word_dict_t` Why would add `_t` suffix, usually meaning `_type` to a variable? `getword(temp1, WORD_LEN+1);` Use `sizeof` instead of repeating size. Like `getword(temp1, sizeof(temp1))` etc.